# Smarter if statement and arrays is not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to create a smarter way to create if statements. I'm writing a function to do this:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_meta' ) ) {
    function get_meta($i) {
        $fname_name = array(
                    'copyright_text',
                    'about_name',
                    'archive_name',
                    'contact_name',
                    'lenguage_name',
                    'cc_name',
                    'about_link',
                    'archive_link',
                    'contact_link',
                    'lenguage_link',
                    'cc_link',
                    'about_editors_name',
                    'about_responsibility_name',
                    'about_joinus_name',
                    'about_editors_link',
                    'about_responsibility_link',
                    'about_joinus_link'
                    );
        foreach( $fname_name as $fname )
            include_once( get_option($fname));

        if ( $i ) return $fname_name[$i];
    }
}
```

But when this function is called, it returns this error:

> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'what' for inclusion (include_path='.;php\PEAR') in local\wp-content\themes\net\0.6\functions.php on line 398

Basically, just want to add `get_option('');` to each array, to return for example:

```
get_option('copyright_text');
```

or even more specific, to return:

```
get_option('copyright_text', '');
```

FIXED:

Okay, I just fix this by myself, but I'm so grateful of any advice here.

Instead using `foreach` and `include_once`, I use an even more simple solution:

```
if ($i) return get_option($fname_name[$i], '');
else if ($i == 0) return get_option($fname_name[0], '');
```

Comment: There's one problem that's immediately obvious: you're returning `$fname[$i]`, when no variable named `$fname` exists at that point.

Comment: And how's `get_option()` defined? Or a better question, what are you trying to do here? This code has a bad smell to it.

Comment: I'd add echo json_encode(get_option($fname)) into that foreach statement to see what this get_option returns.

Comment: Making a simple thing into complicated isn't smarter way i suppose?

Comment: I'm doing this because I don't want to write hundred of if statements.

Comment: @IgnacioTrujillo Why would you have to write hundreds of if statements? What exactly do these includes do? Are they just HTML or do they contain PHP code? Is `get_meta()` supposed to return the contents of the included file(s)?

Comment: @NullUserException yeah, get_meta is intended to do that.

Comment: @IgnacioTrujillo I see that you accepted my answer. Does that mean that it worked? I'm extremely curious as to how that happened, because like I said, your `get_info()` has infinite recursion in it and should not work at all.

Comment: @NullUserException see the edit. I screwed my code using foreach and include_once, so I used two if statements and the code work like a charm.

Comment: @IgnacioTrujillo Ok, if you say so... Don't take this the wrong way, but I'd still advise you to start slower because it doesn't look like you know what you're doing. It's much better to understand what each line of code does than to follow code others write without really understanding what's going on. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 foreach( $fname_name as $fname ){
        include_once( get_option($fname));
       if ( $i ) return $fname;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are creating a shortcut for writing accessor methods.  You would do yourself some good to take a look at PHP's magic methods.  Specifically pay attention to __get, __set, and __call.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

In this case, what you are doing looks similiar to the following:

```
class myClass {

    // This could be associated with whatever other data you are interested in
    private $_meta = array(
                'copyright_text',
                'about_name',
                'archive_name',
                'contact_name',
                'lenguage_name',
                'cc_name',
                'about_link',
                'archive_link',
                'contact_link',
                'lenguage_link',
                'cc_link',
                'about_editors_name',
                'about_responsibility_name',
                'about_joinus_name',
                'about_editors_link',
                'about_responsibility_link',
                'about_joinus_link'
                );

    public function __get($name) {
        if (in_array($name, $this->_meta)) {
            return $this->_meta[$name];
        }
    }
}
```